# is it possible to change an element on responsiveness?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

just wondering if it's possible to change a div to an input at a certain breakpoint?

I have a div that contains some names in and then when I switch to mobile, I want this div to become editable so I can change the names.

I guess I have 2 options, change the element type or make the onChange function only applicable on mobile.

is either possible?

can post code but essentially just want a guide or solution how to do this

Comment: Couldn't you just have an input at the same location but hidden with media queries above a certain viewport width?

Comment: You cant change input to div or vice-versa, you can only exchange them. Is it something you are looking for?

Comment: you can't change an element type with css.  You have way more options though. 1. style the input to look like a text div above a breakpoint 2. put multiple elements on the page and change the display property based on screen width

Comment: You can also consider using the contenteditable attribute, and changing that with js in mobile. FWIW There was a "user-modify" css feature at least for mox and webkit, but is removed from standards and deprecated https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-moz-user-modify

Answer (score 0):

First, to detect a mobile browser, you can use

```
  if(/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
```

Then, on your page, use two elements - the div and the input (or a textarea) and just keep one of them hidden at all times. It seems like you want to listen for a click on the DIV to enable the INPUT, or? And you'll want a key listener on the input to update the DIV as well as another listener to handle hiding the input field and showing the DIV again